# Where can I report bitcoin scammers?

Tags: fraud

The following bitcoin addresses are involved in FRAUD...

[snip]

Where can I report bitcoin scammers?

Comment: What would reporting their addresses accomplish? They could just generate new ones.

Comment: report fraud/scam bitcoin addresses via http://bitcoinwhoswho.com/address/THE_BITCOIN_ADDRESS You need to register first. Note that BTC addresses are linked to BTC wallets which are linked to people. Does reporting this way actually DO anything? Dunno.

Answer (score 8):

In general bitcoin means: "if you don't own the keys, you don't own the coins" (for example web wallets or exchanges) and "if you hand over the keys (have them stolen) or sign a transaction to the wrong destination (buy a cheap iPhone from Nigeria) then you just learned a lesson the hard way".

Having said that, Bitcoin does offer some unique protection methods like multisignature and wallet backups.

Depending on the situation and the kind of fraud, you might be able to contact your local law enforcement or FBI or equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

Report fraud to your local police.

If you know how to find the Internet Service Provider (ISP) of a website, you can report the website to their ISP.

Remember that Bitcoin is like cash. No supervisor is in charge of your cash payments, there is no central authority. When someone tricks you out of cash, you don't report them to the banknote printer or coin mint, you report them to police.